# How to add labels that are related to particular slice for Pie Chart using coreGraphics iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, pie-chart

I am drawing Pie Chart with Slices based on Array. I need to display specific label 
   related to each slice outside pie chart.

Please suggest any approach to this to implement this.

Thanks in Advance.
   Lakshmi

Comment: How are you drawing the slices? Surely at the point of drawing the slices you need to work out where they go. It doesn't take much to get from there to being able to draw text next to them.

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel. This is a great framework for graphs that has a pie chart in it with all kinds of options for labels: https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/wiki/Example-Graphs